# Subscript out of range, on computers other than mine

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to coding and am using VBA in MS Excel to move values from one workbook to another, run a calculation, and then do an autofilter which brings pertinent data back into the original workbook.

I'm running into a problem that has me stumped..  My code works perfectly on my computer, but does not work on a server location, or when saved locally on another machine.  The file path isn't the problem - part of this code opens the necessary spreadsheet, and that part of the code works fine.  Error 9 displays as soon as the code instructs the software to make the value in one named range the same as the same named range on another workbook.  I've tried a few different things to no avail and haven't been able to find anything helpful on this website.

Please halp!  I'd also love to be critiqued so that I can learn more from this.  If you have suggestions on how I could clean this up let me know!

```
    Sub TIMECALCULATION()

'START TOOL DIMENSION OUTPUT FROM ITEM WORKSHEET TO MACHINE MASTER FOR SETUP & CYLE TIME CALCULATION
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Machine Master.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim Ret

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("MACHINE MASTER")
    Set wb2 = Application.ThisWorkbook

    Dim ws5 As Worksheet, ws6 As Worksheet
    Set ws5 = wb1.Worksheets("INPUT")
    Set ws6 = wb2.Worksheets("CALCULATION PAGE")

With ws5

    .Range("SERIES").Value = ws6.Range("SERIES").Value
    .Range("FLUTES").Value = ws6.Range("FLUTES").Value
    .Range("CTRCUT").Value = ws6.Range("CTRCUT").Value
    .Range("PLUNGING").Value = ws6.Range("PLUNGING").Value
    .Range("SERIESREVISION").Value = ws6.Range("SERIESREVISION").Value

    .Range("BLANKLEN").Value = ws6.Range("BLANKLEN").Value
    .Range("BLANKDIA").Value = ws6.Range("BLANKDIA").Value
    .Range("BLANKFIN").Value = ws6.Range("BLANKFIN").Value
    .Range("COOLTHRUTYPE").Value = ws6.Range("COOLTHRUTYPE").Value

    .Range("ITEMNUM").Value = ws6.Range("ITEMNUM").Value
    .Range("ITEMREVISION").Value = ws6.Range("ITEMREVISION").Value

    .Range("ROTATION").Value = ws6.Range("ROTATION").Value
    .Range("FLUTEDIRECTION").Value = ws6.Range("FLUTEDIRECTION").Value
    .Range("PEELGRINDLEN").Value = ws6.Range("PEELGRINDLEN").Value
    .Range("PEELUCUTLEN").Value = ws6.Range("PEELUCUTLEN").Value


    .Range("CUTDIA").Value = ws6.Range("CUTDIA").Value
    If ws6.Range("CUTDIATOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("CUTDIATOL").Value = ws6.Range("CUTDIATOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("CUTDIATOL").Value = ws6.Range("CUTDIATOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("SHKDIA").Value = ws6.Range("SHKDIA").Value
    If ws6.Range("SHKDIATOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("SHKDIATOL").Value = ws6.Range("SHKDIATOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("SHKDIATOL").Value = ws6.Range("SHKDIATOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("LOC").Value = ws6.Range("LOC").Value
    If ws6.Range("LOCTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("LOCTOL").Value = ws6.Range("LOCTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("LOCTOL").Value = ws6.Range("LOCTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("OAL").Value = ws6.Range("OAL").Value
    If ws6.Range("OALTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("OALTOL").Value = ws6.Range("OALTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("OALTOL").Value = ws6.Range("OALTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("ENDWORK").Value = ws6.Range("ENDWORK").Value
    .Range("ENDCORNER").Value = ws6.Range("ENDCORNER").Value
    If .Range("ENDCORNER").Value = "BALL NOSE" Then
        .Range("ENDCORNER").Value = "RADIUS"
        End If
    .Range("FLTBTM").Value = ws6.Range("FLTBTM").Value
    .Range("RADSIZE").Value = ws6.Range("RADSIZE").Value
    If ws6.Range("RADSIZETOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("RADSIZETOL").Value = ws6.Range("RADSIZETOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("RADSIZETOL").Value = ws6.Range("RADSIZETOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("CHAMLEN").Value = ws6.Range("CHAMLEN").Value
    If ws6.Range("CHAMLENTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("CHAMLENTOL").Value = ws6.Range("CHAMLENTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("CHAMLENTOL").Value = ws6.Range("CHAMLENTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("CHAMANG").Value = ws6.Range("CHAMANG").Value
    If ws6.Range("CHAMANGTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("CHAMANGTOL").Value = ws6.Range("CHAMANGTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("CHAMANGTOL").Value = ws6.Range("CHAMANGTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("POINTANG").Value = ws6.Range("POINTANG").Value
    If ws6.Range("POINTANGTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("POINTANGTOL").Value = ws6.Range("POINTANGTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("POINTANGTOL").Value = ws6.Range("POINTANGTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("UCUT").Value = ws6.Range("UCUT").Value
    .Range("REACH").Value = ws6.Range("REACH").Value
    If ws6.Range("REACHTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("REACHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("REACHTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("REACHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("REACHTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("NECKDIA1").Value = ws6.Range("NECKDIA1").Value
    If ws6.Range("NECKDIA1TOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("NECKDIA1TOL").Value = ws6.Range("NECKDIA1TOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("NECKDIA1TOL").Value = ws6.Range("NECKDIA1TOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("NECKDIA2").Value = ws6.Range("NECKDIA2").Value
    If ws6.Range("NECKDIA2TOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("NECKDIA2TOL").Value = ws6.Range("NECKDIA2TOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("NECKDIA2TOL").Value = ws6.Range("NECKDIA2TOL").Value
        End If

    .Range("BACKCLEARREQ").Value = ws6.Range("BACKCLEARREQ").Value
    .Range("BACKSIDECUT").Value = ws6.Range("BACKSIDECUT").Value

    .Range("EDGEPREP").Value = ws6.Range("EDGEPREP").Value
    .Range("DBLEND").Value = ws6.Range("DBLEND").Value
    .Range("COATING").Value = ws6.Range("COATING").Value
    .Range("FLAT").Value = ws6.Range("FLAT").Value
    .Range("NUM1FLATLENTYPE").Value = ws6.Range("NUM1FLATLENTYPE").Value

    .Range("REDSHK").Value = ws6.Range("REDSHK").Value
    .Range("REDSHKLEN").Value = ws6.Range("REDSHKLEN").Value
    .Range("REDSHKLENTOL").Value = ws6.Range("REDSHKLENTOL").Value


    .Range("TAPER").Value = ws6.Range("TAPER").Value
    .Range("TAPERDEFMETHOD").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERDEFMETHOD").Value
    .Range("TAPERANG").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERANG").Value
    If ws6.Range("TAPERANGTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("TAPERANGTOL").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERANGTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("TAPERANGTOL").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERANGTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("TAPERCUTTOSHANK").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERCUTTOSHANK").Value

    .Range("UNEQINDX").Value = ws6.Range("UNEQINDX").Value
    .Range("VARHLX").Value = ws6.Range("VARHLX").Value
    .Range("UNEQHLX").Value = ws6.Range("UNEQHLX").Value
    .Range("VARRAKE").Value = ws6.Range("VARRAKE").Value
    .Range("FLTPOL").Value = ws6.Range("FLTPOL").Value
    .Range("HELIX").Value = ws6.Range("HELIX").Value
    .Range("FLUTELEN").Value = ws6.Range("FLUTELEN").Value
    If ws6.Range("FLUTELENTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("FLUTELENTOL").Value = ws6.Range("FLUTELENTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("FLUTELENTOL").Value = ws6.Range("FLUTELENTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("COREDIAF").Value = ws6.Range("COREDIAF").Value
    .Range("PASS2").Value = ws6.Range("PASS2").Value
    .Range("PASS2COREDIAF").Value = ws6.Range("PASS2COREDIAF").Value
    .Range("PASS3").Value = ws6.Range("PASS3").Value
    .Range("PASS3COREDIAF").Value = ws6.Range("PASS3COREDIAF").Value
    .Range("FLT1LEADF").Value = ws6.Range("FLT1LEADF").Value
    .Range("EUROFLT").Value = ws6.Range("EUROFLT").Value
    .Range("EUROFLTHELIX").Value = ws6.Range("EUROFLTHELIX").Value
    .Range("EUROFLTCOREDIAF").Value = ws6.Range("EUROFLTCOREDIAF").Value
    .Range("EUROFLTCORETPR").Value = ws6.Range("EUROFLTCORETPR").Value
    .Range("SKIFLT").Value = ws6.Range("SKIFLT").Value
    .Range("KLAND").Value = ws6.Range("KLAND").Value

    .Range("COREDIAB").Value = ws6.Range("COREDIAB").Value
    .Range("PASS2COREDIAB").Value = ws6.Range("PASS2COREDIAB").Value
    .Range("PASS3COREDIAB").Value = ws6.Range("PASS3COREDIAB").Value
    .Range("ODRELTYPE").Value = ws6.Range("ODRELTYPE").Value
    .Range("CIRLAND").Value = ws6.Range("CIRLAND").Value
    .Range("FLTTYPE").Value = ws6.Range("FLTTYPE").Value
    .Range("ODPOL").Value = ws6.Range("ODPOL").Value
    .Range("ECCLANDWIDTH").Value = ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTH").Value
    If ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("ECCLANDWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("ECCLANDWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("PRIRLFWIDTH").Value = ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTH").Value
    If ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("PRIRLFWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("PRIRLFWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("SECRELIEF").Value = ws6.Range("SECRELIEF").Value
    .Range("SECRLFWIDTH").Value = ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTH").Value
    If ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("SECRLFWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("SECRLFWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("ECCLANDWIDTHB").Value = ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHB").Value
    If ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHBTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("ECCLANDWIDTHBTOL").Value = ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHBTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("ECCLANDWIDTHBTOL").Value = ws6.Range("ECCLANDWIDTHBTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("PRIRLFWIDTHB").Value = ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHB").Value
    If ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHBTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("PRIRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value = ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("PRIRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value = ws6.Range("PRIRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("SECRLFWIDTHB").Value = ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHB").Value
    If ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHBTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("SECRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value = ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("SECRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value = ws6.Range("SECRLFWIDTHBTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("EGPREP").Value = ws6.Range("EGPREP").Value
    .Range("EDGEPREPSHAPE").Value = ws6.Range("EDGEPREPSHAPE").Value
    .Range("EDGEPREPSIZE").Value = ws6.Range("EDGEPREPSIZE").Value

    .Range("GRIOW").Value = ws6.Range("GRIOW").Value
    .Range("GASHRAD").Value = ws6.Range("GASHRAD").Value
    .Range("GASHWHLANG").Value = ws6.Range("GASHWHLANG").Value
    .Range("GASHANG").Value = ws6.Range("GASHANG").Value
    .Range("GASHWALKANG").Value = ws6.Range("GASHWALKANG").Value

    .Range("SECENDRELIEF").Value = ws6.Range("SECENDRELIEF").Value
    .Range("TERTIARY").Value = ws6.Range("TERTIARY").Value
    .Range("WIPERFLAT").Value = ws6.Range("WIPERFLAT").Value
    .Range("WIPERFLATWIDTH").Value = ws6.Range("WIPERFLATWIDTH").Value
    If ws6.Range("WIPERFLATWIDTHTOL").Offset(0, -1).Value = "±" Then
        .Range("WIPERFLATWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("WIPERFLATWIDTHTOL").Value * 2
        Else
        .Range("WIPERFLATWIDTHTOL").Value = ws6.Range("WIPERFLATWIDTHTOL").Value
        End If
    .Range("TIPNOTCH").Value = ws6.Range("TIPNOTCH").Value
    .Range("NOTCHDEPTH").Value = ws6.Range("NOTCHDEPTH").Value
    .Range("NOTCHWIDTH").Value = ws6.Range("NOTCHWIDTH").Value

    .Range("RAKESURF").Value = ws6.Range("RADROUNDING").Value
    .Range("SGASH").Value = ws6.Range("SGASH").Value

    .Range("CHISELDIA").Value = ws6.Range("CHISELDIA").Value

    .Range("CHIPBRKR").Value = ws6.Range("CHIPBRKR").Value
    .Range("CHIPBRKRSHAPE").Value = ws6.Range("CHIPBRKRSHAPE").Value
    .Range("CHIPBRKRDEPTH").Value = ws6.Range("CHIPBRKRDEPTH").Value
    .Range("CHIPBRKRPITCH").Value = ws6.Range("CHIPBRKRPITCH").Value
    .Range("CHIPBRKRSTART").Value = ws6.Range("CHIPBRKRSTART").Value
    .Range("CHIPBRKRRAD").Value = ws6.Range("CHIPBRKRRAD").Value
    .Range("COBBPITCH").Value = ws6.Range("COBBPITCH").Value
    .Range("COBBSTART").Value = ws6.Range("COBBSTART").Value

    .Range("ROUGHSPIN").Value = ws6.Range("ROUGHSPIN").Value
    .Range("SPINTOFINAL").Value = ws6.Range("SPINTOFINAL").Value
    .Range("SPUNPOLISH").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNPOLISH").Value
    .Range("SPUNDIA").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNDIA").Value
    .Range("SPUNLEN").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNLEN").Value
    .Range("LEADOUTANG").Value = ws6.Range("LEADOUTANG").Value
    .Range("SPINTAPER").Value = ws6.Range("SPINTAPER").Value
    .Range("TAPERSPINTOSHANK").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERSPINTOSHANK").Value
    .Range("SPUNTAPERENDSHARP").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNTAPERENDSHARP").Value
    .Range("SPUNDIA2").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNDIA2").Value
    .Range("TAPERLEADOUTLEN").Value = ws6.Range("TAPERLEADOUTLEN").Value
    .Range("SPUNTAPERLEN").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNTAPERLEN").Value
    .Range("SPUNTAPERANG").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNTAPERANG").Value
    .Range("SPINCHAM").Value = ws6.Range("SPINCHAM").Value
    .Range("SPUNCHAMDIA1").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNCHAMDIA1").Value
    .Range("SPUNCHAMDIA2").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNCHAMDIA2").Value
    .Range("SPUNCHAMANG").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNCHAMANG").Value
    .Range("SPUNCHAMLEN1").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNCHAMLEN1").Value
    .Range("SPUNCHAMLEN2").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNCHAMLEN2").Value
    .Range("TOUCHANDTAKE").Value = ws6.Range("TOUCHANDTAKE").Value
    .Range("SPINPOINT").Value = ws6.Range("SPINPOINT").Value
    .Range("SPUNPOINTTIPDIA").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNPOINTTIPDIA").Value
    .Range("SPUNPOINTOD").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNPOINTOD").Value
    .Range("SPUNPOINTANG").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNPOINTANG").Value
    .Range("SPUNPOINTLEN").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNPOINTLEN").Value
    .Range("CNCFIRSTPLUNGE").Value = ws6.Range("CNCFIRSTPLUNGE").Value
    .Range("SPINUCUT").Value = ws6.Range("SPINUCUT").Value
    .Range("FULLPREUCUT").Value = ws6.Range("FULLPREUCUT").Value
    .Range("PRECNCMANDISH").Value = ws6.Range("PRECNCMANDISH").Value
    .Range("BKSDCLNUP").Value = ws6.Range("BKSDCLNUP").Value
    .Range("PREUCUTCNCLOC").Value = ws6.Range("PREUCUTCNCLOC").Value
    .Range("SPUNCUTDIALEN").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNCUTDIALEN").Value
    .Range("BACKSIDEANG").Value = ws6.Range("BACKSIDEANG").Value
    .Range("SPUNNECKF").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNNECKF").Value
    .Range("SPUNNECKB").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNNECKB").Value
    .Range("SPUNREACH").Value = ws6.Range("SPUNREACH").Value
    .Range("CUT").Value = ws6.Range("CUT").Value
    .Range("CUTWHEN").Value = ws6.Range("CUTWHEN").Value
    .Range("GRINDOAL").Value = ws6.Range("GRINDOAL").Value
    .Range("OALGRINDPURPOSE").Value = ws6.Range("OALGRINDPURPOSE").Value
    .Range("NUM1FLATLEN").Value = ws6.Range("NUM1FLATLEN").Value
    .Range("WELDONCOUNT").Value = ws6.Range("WELDONCOUNT").Value

End With
'END DATA OUTPUT TO MACHINE MASTER


'CLEAR ANY EXISITING ROUTING DATA IN THE CURRENT WORKBOOK
wb2.Sheets("ROUTING").Range("2:1048576").Delete


Application.Calculate

'START DATA INPUT FROM MACHINE MASTER
'THE FOLLOWING CODE AUTOFILTERS THE FULL ROUTINGS ON TABS 1, 2, & 3 IN THE MACHINE MASTER WORKBOOK AND PASTES THAT INFORMATION IN THIS ITEM WORKBOOK ON THE ROUTING WORKSHEET.

    'Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim strSearch As String


    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("1")
    Set ws2 = wb1.Worksheets("2")
    Set ws3 = wb1.Worksheets("3")

    strSearch = "Y"

    With ws1

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws4 = wb2.Worksheets("ROUTING")

    With ws4
        'lRow = 2
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With



    With ws2

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws4 = wb2.Worksheets("ROUTING")

    With ws4
        'lRow = 2
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With



    With ws3

        .AutoFilterMode = False

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws4 = wb2.Worksheets("ROUTING")

    With ws4
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With

wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: **On which line does the error occur?**

Comment: you have lots of fields hardcoded, make sure that the names of the fields match, workbook names, range names, etc.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent's is the first important learning critic: please don't forget to state the line of code where the error is occurring ;)

Comment: That's a lot of repeating actions. With two identical magic strings in each line. Your code screams to be done in a loop.

Comment: from what I read in the question it's this line `.Range("SERIES").Value = ws6.Range("SERIES").Value`

Comment: [**Subscript out of range (Error 9)** on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264179(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: @Jason delete all value replacement except one or two to make code simpler for tracking the source of error. And follow what others posted in previous comments.

Comment: The most likely cause of that error on certain computers only would be this line: `Set wb1 = Workbooks("MACHINE MASTER")` which should really be `Set wb1 = Workbooks("MACHINE MASTER.XLSM")`. Or better still set it when you open: `Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Machine Master.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)`

Comment: What version of Office are you using, and what versions are they using?   I would take the time and make a table for all those if statements.  Have the code look up a value and then the result you would have.  Having all those If statements is rough, especially if you have to change any of the information.  If a price gets changed or something, you would want to update those values in a table, not 100 lines of vba to sift through.  Make yourself a function that when you pass in something, a result happens, then loop through all your items and put them into the same function.

Comment: @Malachi - I'm assuming that all the workbook & range names are correct based on them working on my computer.  Let me know why that's not a good assumption if it isn't please.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent & Matteo NNZ - of course!! ha! Right after "With Ws5" the first line where I'm using .value=.value and every value=value line thereafter.  I've tried using cell references to and that doesn't work for me either.  At first I had the workbook and worksheet names hard coded in each line, but I read on this site that it's best to use Dim.  I'm tryin here!! :)

Comment: @Jason, like the answer that was left by rkwadd says, you need to make sure that your paths are correct on the computer that it isn't working on. one thing that you might also want to look into is what version of Excel you are using  on both computers, maybe there is something about the versions that are being used that prevents the code from operating as expected

Comment: @Taosique - I love the idea of a loop.  I'd love an example as I've never done one.  I'll look up what I can on my own, but I'm under the gun and my time is running short.  So I'd just list out the named ranges whose values I need transferred and then the same line of code will work over and over again?  That's cool :)

Comment: @PJ - I'm using 2013 and they're on 2010.  Could be an issue.. but I don't know what to change to make this compatible. Again.. total newbie at this stuff. The values are in all in the named ranges in excel and there are no hard coded values in this code with one exception that I'll live with.  I multiply some values by 2 based on the value in a cell offset from the named range I reference.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that ThisWorkbook.Path is returning the expected path by using `debug.print`. In the VBA editor first go to View => Immediate Window, then run `debug.print ThisWorkbook.Path` on your machine and on the machines it's not working with.

Also cutting tools are awesome. The ISO13399 standard for cutting tools might make this data much easier to maintain in the future. I know certain large vendors are trying to sell the capability that you've built into this worksheet (for a large amount of money).

Comment: Cutting tools ARE awesome.  This project allows my company to fully define all of a product line's dimensions, tols, and constraints, calculate the values for custom sizes, creates an inspection report, xml for CAM, calculates 3 alternate routings for use in scheduling and quoting and arranges it for import into our new ERP software.  Thanks for lead on ISO13399.  I wasn't aware of it and will adjust all of my non-conforming dimension abbreviations to match up with the standard.

Comment: Take a look at MachiningCloud GmbH, Kennametal Novo, and TDM Systems (Sandvik) for more on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

@Rory - The answer was to change the filepath to Workbooks("Machine Master.xlsm")

Thank you, thank you, thank you to all of you for your suggestions and your time!!!  I'm looking forward to being a part of this community and to contributing to other folks as I can.  Have a fantastic weekend!

-J